# How to resolve this error in GetRepository of TypeORM: ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRepository')

Tags: mysql, typescript, docker, nestjs, typeorm

> [Nest] 171  - 08/31/2022, 8:35:42 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot
> read properties of undefined (reading 'getRepository') tenant-node   |
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'getRepository') tenant-node   |     at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as
> metatype]
> (/var/www/app/src/infrastruture/providers/tenant.provider.ts:6:56)
> tenant-node   |     at Injector.instantiateClass
> (/var/www/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:343:55)
> tenant-node   |     at callback
> (/var/www/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:53:45)
> tenant-node   |     at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) tenant-node   |     at
> Injector.resolveConstructorParams
> (/var/www/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:132:24)
> tenant-node   |     at Injector.loadInstance
> (/var/www/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:57:13)
> tenant-node   |     at Injector.loadProvider
> (/var/www/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:84:9)
> tenant-node   |     at async Promise.all (index 3) tenant-node   |
> at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders
> (/var/www/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:47:9)
> tenant-node   |     at
> /var/www/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:32:13

My tenant.provider.ts:

```
import { DataSource, getRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import { TenantSchema } from "../db/TenantSchemas.schema";

export const TenantProviders = [{
    provide: 'TENANT_REPOSITORY',
    useFactory: (dataSource: DataSource) => dataSource.getRepository(TenantSchema),
    Inject: ['DATA_SOURCE']
}, ];
```

My app.module.ts:

```
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
    const envTenant = ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true
    })
    import { TenantModule } from './tenant.module';
    import { TenantProviders } from '../infrastruture/providers/tenant.provider';
    import { TenantTypeOrmRepository } from '../infrastruture/db/TypeOrmRepository';
    import { DBTenant } from '../infrastruture/db/connections/db.tenant';
    import { TenantController } from './tenant.controller';
    
    @Module({
      imports: [
        envTenant,
        DBTenant,
        //TenantModule
      ],
      controllers: [TenantController],
      providers: [
        ...TenantProviders,
        TenantTypeOrmRepository
      ],
    })
    export class AppModule {}

My TenantSchema.schema.ts:
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class TenantSchema {
    constructor(tRepository?: Partial<TenantSchema>) {
        this.id = tRepository?.id;
        this.name = tRepository?.name;
        this.tenant = tRepository?.tenant;
        this.isActive = tRepository?.isActive;
    }

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ length: 128 })
    name:string;

    @Column({ length: 10 })
    tenant:string;

    @Column({ default: false })
    isActive:boolean;
}
```

My db.provider.ts

```
import { appDataSource } from './app.source';

export const dbProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'DATA_SOURCE',
    useFactory: async () => {
      return appDataSource.initialize();
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: hello, could you share the complete way of how the multi tenant works?

Comment: Shouldn't you be awaiting the result of the asynchronous factory?

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same problem as you, but I figured out what was going on:

I unknowingly had set up the same **PORT** for both my *Express* and *Data-Source*, so both were trying to connect to PORT 3000 at the same time. Upon setting Express to 3000 and Data-Source to 5432, everything started working again.